# Cannot delete a records (OneToMany) with Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, cascading-deletes

I have 2 entities linked together PICTURE <-(OneToMany)-> NOTE (see class details below). When I tried to delete a picture record I got the following message from Symfony

> An exception occurred while executing 'DELETE FROM Picture WHERE id =
>   ?' with params [118]: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation:
>   1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint
>   fails (`symfony`.`note`, CONSTRAINT `FK_6F8F552A8671F084` FOREIGN KEY
>   (`picture_id`) REFERENCES `Picture` (`id`))

**I find it strange because if the note.author_id is the same as the current user, then I can delete the picture (and the note associated to the picture) without any problem.**

here some details of my class picture and note:

```php
Class Picture
{
   /**
   * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="XXX\XXXBundle\Entity\Note", mappedBy="picture", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
   * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="note_id", referencedColumnName="picture_id", onDelete="CASCADE")
   **/
   private $notes;
}
```

```php
Class Note
{
   /**
   * @ORM\Id
   * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="XXX\XXXBundle\Entity\Picture", inversedBy="notes") 
   **/
   private $picture;

   /**
   * @ORM\Id
   * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Sdz\UserBundle\Entity\User", cascade={"persist"})
   */
   private $user;
}
```

Here my controller to delete the picture. FYI picture is a collection in my form. I set the option *allow_delete* to true

```
    foreach($pictures as $picture) // $pictures is the initial list of picture
    {  
      if(false === $data_form->getPictures()->contains($picture))
      {
          $em->remove($picture);
      }
    }
```

Comment: Can you add code how you try to delete these entities?

Comment: ok I just added it to my question (at the bottom). what is really strenge is that it works fine unless the note is not posted by the current user...

Answer (score -1):

You have constraints on database that prevents you from cascaded deleting. I would suggest to use phpMyAdmin tool (mysql command line would be horrible to use for checking constraints): open both tables structure tab, go into relational view, and here check how constraints are set.

You may have different constraints set inside doctrine mappings and inside database, and it may work fine, until you try to perform an action on database, that collides with database constraints, like here.

Comment: ok FIsher, before I user phpMyAdmin tool, what kind of constraints make the database works fine to delete picture when the note author is the current user... and not works when the note author is not the current user?

Comment: That depends what do you want to happen when you delete picture. If you want associated note to be deleted as well, make constraint CASCADE.

Comment: Yes I want notes associated to picture to be deleted. this is why I set up onDelete="CASCADE" in my comments on the class Picture. (and it works fine unless the notes associated to picture have author_id which is different from current user, which is very strange) if note.author.id = current_user.id then I do not have the symfony exception which is triggered.

Comment: Then i got no idea. Seems that problem is somewhere deeper.Actually error message says it straight: constrains permits deleting, I would remove all of them from database and then tried.

Comment: ok, how can I delete constrains form the database? btw I do not have the relational view button (even by setting storage engine to "innoDB")